# Deriving and defining $e^x$, $\log_b(x)$, $\ln(x)$, and their derivatives?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, logarithms, euler-mascheroni-constant

I am trying to understand the definition and evaluation of $e^x$ and $\log(x)$ and $ln(x)$ and their derivatives, but I can't help but feel that a lot of this stuff is circular. Every time I google this subject or ask about it I feel like people give explanations that depend on one of these other concepts, but then when asking about those other concepts, they define it in terms of the very thing I was originally asking about. I admit I'm finding this frustrating.

I'm trying to start from one piece and move onto the next without assuming knowledge or already pre-supposing the result.

Assume that we have this prior knowledge:

A derivative for function $f(x)$ is defined as:

$$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$$

For $e$, pretend we've defined this from the compound interest problem but we haven't actually evaluated it yet:

$$e = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$

Okay:

1. How do we evaluate $e$, so we can at the very least define something like $\ln(x) = \log_e(x)$.
2. How do we show that when $f(x) = e^x$, then $f'(x) = e^x$?
3. How do we show that when $f(x) = \log_b(x)$, then $f'(x) = \frac{1}{x \ln(b)}$?

I realize this is a three-part question but if I ask any one of these in isolation people will inevitably answer them in a circular way which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Your approach is not the standard one. Most books that I have seen define $\ln x=\int_1^x\frac 1t\,dt$, find its properties, define its inverse function as $\exp(x)$, find its properties, define $e=\exp(0)$, show $\exp(x)=e^r$ for rational values of $r$, and define $e^x=\exp(x)$ for all real $x$. Do you want details on that approach?

Comment: @Rory, I think most intro Calculus texts don't take that approach (though it's a good one).

Comment: Having defined $e$ (as that limit), I don't see why there's any need to evaluate $e$ in order to define the natural logarithm function.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm going on the assumption that we have to know what the value is if we are going to actually perform calculations with it later

Comment: @RoryDaulton The problem is that that integral comes out of nowhere with no explanation. Why is it defined that way? What reason do we have to define that in the first place? The reason I'm asking these questions is that I want to understand where all of this comes from without pulling random definitions out of thin air. I'm trying to start from the basics and work my way up so at all times I know everything prior.

Comment: For instance I normally define a logarithm as a transformation between $a = \log_b(x)$ and $b^a = x$

Comment: @user525966 this question is similar to a question you previously posted which seems to have received an answer (I have actually answered your question using the binomial theorem which is a formal approach). There are *many* questions regarding this topic on this site. Some people have posted the links of some sources on the comment section on you previous question. If you want a reference you can look Spivak’s Calculus. I don’t find it useful for you to keep on posting the same question but wording it differently!

Comment: @Denis28 Spivak's calculus pulls this stuff out of thin air, too. I wouldn't make the question if I already had an answer! I'm looking for derivations that explain their definitions without just pulling them out of nowhere. None of the comments on that page lead to other pages that answer these questions.

Comment: @user525966 look at the answer that I put involving the binomial theorem. Defining the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{n!}$ as $e$ was purely arbitrary. Euler could’ve have called the constant that such series converges to as $a$. Take a look at that proof and then everything follows. Notice that I did not use explicitly $e$ in none of the steps so the argument is not circular. Also, if you are having trouble understanding limits, how are you going to understand more advanced topics? At the math knowledge you currently have, you should accept some things as they are.

Comment: @Denis28 I understand how to _use_ things fine (limits, derivatives, logs, integrals, etc), but I want to know where things come from rather than just blindly memorizing facts. I want to see where the facts arise and how we get there. For instance most people just blindly accept that the derivative of $\log_b(x)$ is $\frac{1}{x\ln(b)}$ with no explanation as to why it is.

Comment: The explanation for _that_ usually involves invoking $\ln(x)$ with no reason or context, which brings things back to $e^x$, etc.

Comment: Well I gave you the explanation that did not use $e$ and $\ln$, didn’t I? But you asked the question once again. This means that you did not understand my proof, which implies that you don’t have the toolset to fully understand the answer to your question. I think that your will is admirable but sometimes if you don’t have the knowledge, you just have to wait until you obtain it.  It is no good to keep on insisting on something that requires advanced topics which you don’t have familiarity with. If you want a rigorous proof there is no easy way. That’s why most calculus book don’t cover it.

Comment: I understand your proofs fine, I just disagree that they answer my question here

Comment: @user525966 if you define $e$, which I did, and look at other answers to define $e^x$, then everything else just follows. You can define $\ln(x)$ as its inverse and from there you can notice all the nice properties. What more are you looking for?

Comment: In one of your previous questions, I told that you need to get familiar with at least one approach and gave references for that. Did you have a look at them? Right now it appears that you are trying to mix multiple approaches and getting confused.

Comment: It's quite natural to ask, how far to the right of $x=1$ do you have to go before the area under the graph of $y=1/x$ is 1? It's easy to work out that the answer is somewhere between 2 and 3. Call it $e$, and take it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $$e = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$

you may define

$$e^x = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n$$

and define $ ln x $ as the inverse function of $e^x$.

For finding derivative of of $e^x$ you need  properties of $e^x$ and for derivative of ln x you may use formula for derivative of inverse functions.

The other approach is to start with definition of lnx as an integral $$ lnx = \int _1^x \frac {1}{t} dt$$ and define $e^x$ as the inverse function of $lnx$.

This way makes derivatives almost trivial.

Comment: I am with you on the inverse definition, since if we have $x = e^{f^{-1}(x)}$ then by definition of logs we have $f^{-1}(x)= \log(x) / \log(e) = \log_e(x) = \ln(x)$. Everything after that, you lost me -- I don't see where any of that stuff is coming from.

Comment: You may need to take more advanced courses to cover the theory of integration and differentiation. Some concepts are not quite conprenedable without the formal courses.

Comment: So it's normal, when learning calculus, to just take a lot of this at face value with no explanation or proof for where this stuff comes from? I find it hard to believe that one needs more advanced courses to understand the contents in the simpler courses.

Comment: At this level you accept some facts and later on you learn the theory

Comment: @user525966 many topics that seemed simple needed a long time to be formalized and to be proven. So it does not mean that if a concept is easy to understand then it is easy to prove.

Comment: @user525966: it's rather unfortunate and rather disgusting that calculus is the only subject which is treated so badly. No other math topic starts with a lack of proofs.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I'm finding myself frustrated at it -- as I go through these topics from scratch, how often things are just presented without any proofs whatsoever

Comment: @user525966: you may get rid of your frustration by studying Hardy's classic *A Course of Pure Mathematics* (like I did).

Answer (score 1):

So one of the problems you've got is that just defining the number $e$ doesn't get you very far towards defining $e^x$; after all, defining $e^x$ for irrational $x$ might require some sort of definition on the rationals and an extension by continuity. Probably not going to be as insightful as you might hope.

So I'd suggest going in the complete opposite direction.

**Step 1.** Define $\log x = \int_1^x \frac 1 t \, dt$. Then clearly $\log x$ is a monotonically increasing, continuous function whose derivative is $1/x$. All the usual properties of $\log$, such as $\log(ab) = \log a + \log b$, follow easily from changes of variables and algebra.

**Step 2.** Since $\log$ is monotone, it has an inverse, which we call $\exp$. We now define $e$ to be the unique real number such that $\log e = 1$. The inverse function theorem guarantees that $\exp' = \exp$, just as an application of the derivative of the logarithm.

**Step 3.** Notice that recasting all the usual logarithm properties through the inverse function gives us all the classical properties of exponentials, such as $exp(a + b) = \exp a \cdot \exp b$.

Now it's easy to define exponentials and logs with other bases.

---

This is the way that's done in a lot of calculus textbooks. The far easier way to deal with things, however, is to *define* $\exp$ via its Taylor series and let $\log$ be its inverse. See, for example, the zeroth chapter of Rudin's Real & Complex Analysis for this.

Comment: Why do we define the log function that way? What connection would this have to any prior mathematics? For example the definition of $e$ arises naturally from the compound interest problem -- where does this log definition come from or where does it arise?

Comment: @user525966 The differential equation underlying the exponential is motivated by "growth proportional to amount" that you see in compound interest. If you view that for the *inverse* function, you get "growth proportional to 1 / time elapsed," which leads to integrating $1/t$.